# Why am I getting an error for the method "TopStudents" in the course class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am new to C++ and am currently trying to extend the course class by adding a method called "TopStudents" that is meant to search the array of student objects to find and print all students with a GPA above a given value(which can be found within the main program).  I have marked the lines I am getting an error on.

When I compile this program I get these error messages:

```
---error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
      students[index].Get(int &uaid, string & name, float &gpa);
                          ^~~
---error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’
      students[index].Get(int &uaid, string & name, float &gpa);
                                            ^
---error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
      students[index].Get(int &uaid, string & name, float &gpa);
                                              ^~~~
---error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
      students[index].Get(int &uaid, string & name, float &gpa);
                                                    ^~~~~
---error: ‘gpa’ was not declared in this scope
      if (gpa >= minGpa) {
          ^~~
```

This is the input I am using:

```
1234 Susan 3.9
2345 John  3.2
3456 Laura 3.8
4567 Brian 3.5
5678 David 3.1
```

Finally, this is my code:

```
////////////////////////////
///////////LAB C////////////INCOMPLETE
////////////////////////////

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
   Student();
   Student(const Student & student);
   ~Student();

   void Set(const int uaid, const string name, const float gpa);
   void Get(int & uaid, string & name, float & gpa) const;
   void Print() const;
   void Read();

private:
   int Uaid;
   string Name;
   float Gpa;
};

Student::Student()
{
   Uaid = 0;
   Name = "none";
   Gpa = 0;
}

Student::Student(const Student & student)
{
   Uaid = student.Uaid;
   Name = student.Name;
   Gpa = student.Gpa;
}

Student::~Student()
{
}

void Student::Set(const int uaid, const string name, const float gpa)
{
   Uaid = uaid;
   Name = name;
   Gpa = gpa;
   if (Gpa < 0.0) Gpa = 0.0;
   else if (Gpa > 4.0) Gpa = 4.0;
}

void Student::Get(int &uaid, string & name, float &gpa) const
{
   uaid = Uaid;
   name = Name;
   gpa = Gpa;
}

void Student::Print() const
{
   cout << Uaid << " " << Name << " " << Gpa << endl;
}

void Student::Read()
{
   cin >> Uaid >> Name >> Gpa;
   if (Gpa < 0.0) Gpa = 0.0;
   else if (Gpa > 4.0) Gpa = 4.0;
}

const int MAX_STUDENTS = 100;
class Course
{
public:
   Course(const int count=0);
   Course(const Course & course);
   ~Course();

   void Print() const;
   void Read();
   void TopStudents(float minGpa);

private:
   Student students[MAX_STUDENTS];
   int num_students;
};

Course::Course(const int count)
{
    cout << "Constructor" << endl;
    num_students = count;
}

Course::Course(const Course & course)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < num_students; index++)
     {
 
     }
}

Course::~Course()
{
    cout << "Destructor" << endl;
}

void Course::Print() const
{
    cout << "Print" << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < num_students; index++)
     {
     students[index].Print();
     }
}

void Course::Read()
{
    cout << "Read" << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < num_students; index++)
     {
     students[index].Read();
     }
}

void Course::TopStudents(float minGpa)
{
    cout << "TopStudents" << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < num_students; index++)
    {
     students[index].Get(int &uaid, string & name, float &gpa); // ERROR
     if (gpa >= minGpa) { // ERROR
         students[index].Print();
     }
    }
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Testing Student class\n";
   Student student1;
   student1.Set(1234, "John", 2.5);
   student1.Print();

   cout << "Testing Course class\n";
   Course course(5);
   course.Print();
   course.Read();
   course.Print();
   course.TopStudents(3.5);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm That's insufficient, because `uaid`, `name`, and `gpa` are actually output parameters. I don't know why `Get` is set up that way, but it is, so somewhere in `Course` or `Course::TopStudents` you would need to declare some variables that can actually be used as arguments to `Get`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just declare new variables on a call to a function.

What you want is probably something like this:

```
int uaid;
string name;
float gpa;
students[index].Get(uaid, name, gpa);
```